# How to do one model's field value automatically come on another model's field in odoo-13?

Tags: inheritance, field, odoo-13

I need sub_total_price field value will come automatically in total_price field .
suppose sub_total_price = 300 then total_price = 300 automatically

```
 *** order.py ***
 class Order_Line(models.Model):
        _name = 'orderline.data'
        _description = "Oder details"
        weight = fields.Float(string="Weight", required=True)
        product_image = fields.Image(string="Image")
        product_quantity = fields.Integer(string="Quantity", required=True)
        making_cost = fields.Integer(string="Making cost", )
        gold_rate = fields.Float(string="Gold Rate", required=True, )
        sub_total_price = fields.Float( compute='gold_cost_count', store=True)
        create_orderline = fields.Many2one('order.order', string="Oder Line")
    
    
    class PaymentLine(models.Model):
        _name = 'paymentline.data'
        # _inherit = 'orderline.data'
        _description = "Payment Details"
    
        price_id = fields.Many2one('orderline.data', )
        total_price = fields.Integer(related='price_id.sub_total_price',string="Total Price")
        advance_payment = fields.Integer(string="Advance payment")
        total_due = fields.Float(string="Total Due")
        create_paymentline = fields.Many2one('order.order', string="Payment Line")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change total_price line to

```
total_price = fields.Float(string="Total Price", related="price_id.sub_total_price", store=True)
```

`store=True` saves the value to the database, else it is fetched in real time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But In this way i have to select one option but i need data automatically
suppose
total_price = Sub_total_price

Comment: Can you kindly help me?

Comment: Can you explain when and how you want the value be there. As i understand there can be more than one line with sub_total_price

Comment: suppose after calculation subtotal value is 300 then it will automatically come total field  
sub_total_price field is one model and total_price is another model's field so my question was 
one model's field value will come automatically another model's field .
if sub_total_price is 450 then automatically total_price will update 450.


Kindly solve this

Comment: you van have sub_total_price 200 and another one with sub_total_price 400. Then what should the total_price be?

Comment: Here i describe  please see
class order(models.Model):
_name = 'order.order '
sub_total_price = 400

class payment(models.Model):
_name= 'payment.payment'

total_price = here will come   sub_total_price value 400 automatically

Comment: Can you kindly help me?

Comment: i believe you have to update `total_price` from  `gold_cost_count`, otherwise you need connection between two lines

Comment: sub_total_price from gold_cost_count this is ok .
now sub_total_price will come on total_price field automatically .

Comment: if you give skypee id then i will send a pic can you kindly help me